# pentaho transpose n columns to one column

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to transpose n columns in inputfields to one column

| firstname | lastname | subject1 | date1 | note1 | subject2 | date2 | note2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| joe | joe | Math | ----- | 15 | Phys | ----- | 10 |
| Judy | judy | Math | ----- | 12 | Phys | ----- | 16 |

to

| firstname | lastname | subject | date | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| joe | joe | Math | ---- | 15 |
| joe | joe | Phys | ---- | 10 |
| Judy | Judy | Math | ---- | 12 |
| Judy | Judy | Phys | ---- | 16 |

Someone knows how can I achieve this? Is there some step that could help or only through scripts?

Answer (score 0):

The Row normaliser or Row denormaliser steps (I never remember which one does the pivot or unpivot operation)

In the directory samples in your installation of pentaho you have examples on how to use common steps and execute common operations, take a look at the examples for those types of steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried Row nomaliser but I didn't get a requested result  .

Comment: So, what have you tried with the Row normaliser step and how have you configured it?